# Dynamic and conditional inserting of new rows that come after a certain Date

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr, zoo

Following are what my data frames look like(Thanks to nice edits from experienced community):

```
library(data.table)
df <- fread('Account       Date     Blue     Red   Amount  
            A          1/1/2016      1        0     100    
            A          2/1/2016      1        1     200    
            B          1/10/2016     0        1     300    
            B          2/10/2016     1        1     400')
df[, Date := as.Date(Date, format="%m/%d/%Y")]

blue <- fread('Date      Amount  
              6/1/2015    55     
              1/31/2016   55     
              2/28/2016   65     
              3/31/2016   75')
blue[, Date := as.Date(Date, format="%m/%d/%Y")]

red <- fread('Date      Amount  
             12/31/2015  43     
             1/15/2016   47     
             2/15/2016   67     
             3/15/2016   77')
red[, Date := as.Date(Date, format="%m/%d/%Y")]
```

In the primary dataframe **df**, **Blue** and **Red** fields depict which category an **Account** belongs to at a given point in time.For example, as of 1/1/2016, Account A only belong to **Blue** category. **blue** and **red** dataframes depict at which dates cash was given out to all accounts in Blue and Red Category. I want to insert new rows in the original **df** with only the rows that come after the **Date** field in **df** from **blue** and **red** dataframes based on whether the account belongs to Blue or Red or both.

The output I am looking for looks like this:

```
  Account       Date         Blue     Red   Amount  
      A          1/1/2016      1        0     100    
      A          1/31/2016     1        0     55
      A          2/1/2016      1        1     200
      A          2/15/2016     1        1     67 
      A          2/28/2016     1        1     65   
      A          3/15/2016     1        1     77    
      A          3/31/2016     1        1     75   
      B          ..............................
```

In the output, as of 1/1/2016 **Account A** only belongs to **Blue** category. My goal is find the date immediately **AFTER** **1/1/2016** in the **blue** table which is **1/31/2016** and then insert it. I don't want to insert **1/15/2016** from the **red** table because account A is not category **Red** as of 1/1/2016. I am ok with Blue and Red fields showing up NA for inserted fields.

My thought was trying `rbind(df, blue, red), by="Account")` but dont know how to incorporate the conditions of only inserting later dates based on which category an Account belongs to at a given point in time.

Comment: The desired output is inconsistent imho: for the first row of `df` you only select the first row that matches the conditions, while for the 2nd row you include more than one. Below you find a solution which selects the first row from the matching rows of `blue` and `red`.

Comment: @ProcrastinatusMaximus as of the first row(1/1/2016), A is only category blue, thats why I put 1/31 from blue table which  is in between 1/1 and 2/1. as of the second row in df(2/1/2016), A is both Blue and Red. That's why I bring all subsequent dates from blue and red tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible approach:

```
# combine the 'blue' & 'red' into one and create an 'colcat' column on the fly
br <- rbindlist(list(blue, red), 
                idcol = 'colcat')[, colcat := c('blue','red')[colcat]]

# loop over the rows of 'df', select the needed rows from 'bluered' 
# and punt the result into a list
brlist <- lapply(df$Date, function(x) br[Date > x][order(Date)])

# loop over the rows, select the needed rows from 'bluered' & bind them together
lst <- lapply(1:nrow(df), function(i) {
  idx <- c('blue','red')[c(c(1)[!!df[i][['Blue']]], c(2)[!!df[i][['Red']]])]
  incs <- brlist[[i]][colcat %in% idx][, .SD[1], colcat][, .(Account = df$Account[i], Date, Blue = df$Blue[i], Red = df$Red[i], Amount)]
  rbind(df[i],incs)
})

# bind the resulting list into one 'data.table' again
DT <- rbindlist(lst)
```

which gives:

```
> DT
    Account       Date Blue Red Amount
 1:       A 2016-01-01    1   0    100
 2:       A 2016-01-31    1   0     55
 3:       A 2016-02-01    1   1    200
 4:       A 2016-02-15    1   1     67
 5:       A 2016-02-28    1   1     65
 6:       B 2016-01-10    0   1    300
 7:       B 2016-01-15    0   1     47
 8:       B 2016-02-10    1   1    400
 9:       B 2016-02-15    1   1     67
10:       B 2016-02-28    1   1     65
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Why is 3/15/2016 and 3/31/2016 not showing up in the output?It is in the combined 'br' table.